# SAS: How do I transfer variables between IML statements?

Tags: variables, macros, sas

Let's say I'm trying to do the following:

```
%macro test(a=);
%do i=1 %to &a;
    proc iml;
        b=b//(2*i);
    quit;
%end;

proc iml;
    print sum(b);
quit;

%mend;

%test(a=2);
```

In the code I'm trying to write, I can't put it all in one IML (I need a proc freq within the do loop). The code above gives the error "Matrix b not set to a value." How do I tell SAS what b is so that I can still access it after I've quit the iml statement?

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

1) Use the [STORE statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/66112/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect412.htm) to write the matrix B to disk at the end of the first call, then use the [LOAD statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/66112/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect215.htm) to read it in during the second call:

```
store B;
quit;

proc freq data=...;
run;

proc iml;
load B;
...
```

2) An alternative approach is to call PROC FREQ from within your PROC IML program by using the [SUBMIT and ENDSUBMIT statements](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/66112/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect413.htm):

```
/* compute B */
submit;
proc freq data=...;
run;
endsubmit;

s = sum(b): /* B is still in scope */
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rework things so the `PROC IML;` and `QUIT;` are outside of the macro.  This is good practice most of the time even in other scenarios where it's not that important, but here it's necessary.

IE

```
%macro test(a=);
%do i=1 %to &a;
        b=b//(2*i);
%end;

proc iml;
%test(a=5);
quit;
```

`QUIT` ends the PROC IML session and clears its memory.